# repair arch linux console

Tags: linux, arch-linux, zsh, console

I was configuring my new arch linux that I just installed.

When I was installing `zsh`, I executed the command `usermod --shell /usr/bin/zsh $USER`, after executing that I got I realized that I forgot to install zsh, and now it gives me many errors and I can't use the console.

How to fix my console?

Do I need to move the configuration of some files or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `usermod` needs root privileges, and you didn't add `sudo` to it in your question, I guess you still have root access to your computer. So, use that to install zsh or to change the shell to bash again.

If you don't have root access, you will have to use other login methods, for example through SSH or X or wayland and do the installation that way.

If you have no other login method than your terminal, then you can still boot a live medium (you know how to do that, that's how you start installing Arch!), mount the root file system, and modify etc/passwd on that to set your user's shell back to /bin/bash.